# Pygame keypress should call function just once

Tags: python, function, pygame, key-events

Hi the title says it basicly all...
To describe it a little more:
it a 2D random tilemap on wich you can move a player and he can mine coal.
The problem is that if he's standing on the coal and pressed space more than one time the coal gets added more then one time to his inventory, AND thats the problem.He can mine more coal even no more is there.
I have searched google but the only thing that i found out was that i have to use flag , some boolean values ...but HOW ?

I know the code is written were dirty,ugly etc...can be optimized...

```
import random
import pygame
import Images_raw
from colors import *
from timeit import default_timer as timer


pygame.init()
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pygame Display settings
display_width=704;  display_height=512
gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('2D Coal miner')

# Misc
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
mouseX=int;    mouseY=int

class Map:
    def __init__(self):
        global mapp,mapSize,mappSurfaces,QD_array,inventory,ammount,minedCoal
        mapSize=100
        ammount=0
        mapp=[[random.randint(0,1) for i in range(mapSize)] for i in range(mapSize)]
        mappSurfaces=mapp
        QD_array=[[random.randint(0,1) for i in range(mapSize)] for i in range(mapSize)]
        inventory=[[{'item':ammount} for i in range(5)] for i in range(5)]
        minedCoal=[]

    def createMap(self):
        global tileImage,recti,coalRect_list,chacheList
        tileImage=pygame.Surface
        coalRect=pygame.Surface
        coalRect_list=[]
        chacheList=[]

        for i in range(mapSize):
            for j in range(mapSize):
                randNum=random.randint(0,11)
                randNum2=random.randint(0,1)

                if randNum == 0 and randNum2==1:
                    tileImage= Images_raw.coal_img
                    QD_array[i][j]=0

                elif randNum== 2 and randNum2<= 9:
                    tileImage= Images_raw.water_img
                    QD_array[i][j]=1

                elif randNum>= 3 or randNum2>= 12:
                    tileImage= Images_raw.grass_img
                    QD_array[i][j]=2

                elif randNum== 5 or randNum2== 5:
                    tileImage= Images_raw.stone_img
                    QD_array[i][j]=3
                else:
                    tileImage= Images_raw.dirt_img
                    QD_array[i][j]=4

                mappSurfaces[i][j]=tileImage

        for k in range(mapSize):
            for l in range(mapSize):
                if QD_array[k][l]==0:
                    coalRect=pygame.Rect(k*32,l*32,32,32)
                    coalRect_list.append(coalRect)
                else:
                    pass

    def mineCoalAt(self,noCoal):

        for i in range(mapSize):
            for j in range(mapSize):
                if QD_array[i][j]==0:
                    chacheList.append((i,j))

        x=chacheList[noCoal][0]
        y=chacheList[noCoal][1]

        QD_array[x][y]=10

        inventory[0][0]['item']+=1

    def update(self,x_dif,y_dif):
        for i in range(mapSize):
            for j in range(mapSize):
                if QD_array[i][j] == 0:
                    tileImage= Images_raw.coal_img

                elif QD_array[i][j]== 1:
                    tileImage= Images_raw.water_img

                elif QD_array[i][j]== 2:
                    tileImage= Images_raw.grass_img

                elif QD_array[i][j]== 3:
                    tileImage= Images_raw.stone_img

                elif QD_array[i][j]== 10:
                    tileImage= Images_raw.coalUsed_img
                else:
                    tileImage= Images_raw.dirt_img

                mappSurfaces[i][j]=tileImage
                gameDisplay.blit(mappSurfaces[i][j],(x_dif+(i*32),y_dif+(j*32)),None,0)


#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Main game function
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def gameLoop():
    gameExit=False; outRight=False
    player_X=11;   player_Y=8
    allowMovement=False
    moveRight,moveLeft,moveUp,moveDown=False,False,False,False
    Space,sSpace=False,False
    x_difference,y_difference=0,0
    mapO=Map()
    mapO.createMap()
    counter=0
    allowMovement=True


    while not gameExit:
#-----------event loop---------------------------------------------------------
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                gameExit = True

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key == pygame.K_DOWN):
                    moveDown=True
                elif(event.key == pygame.K_UP):
                    moveUp=True
                elif(event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
                    moveLeft=True
                elif(event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
                    moveRight=True
                elif(event.key == pygame.K_p):
                    print(player_X*32,player_Y*32)
                elif(event.key == pygame.K_SPACE):
                    Space=True
                elif(event.key == pygame.K_i):
                    print(inventory)

            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if (event.key == pygame.K_DOWN):
                    moveDown=False
                elif(event.key == pygame.K_UP):
                    moveUp=False
                elif(event.key == pygame.K_LEFT):
                    moveLeft=False
                elif(event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT):
                    moveRight=False
                elif(event.key == pygame.K_SPACE):
                    Space=False


#-----------event loop END-----------------------------------------------------
        a=len(coalRect_list)

        #Logical/Main part

        if allowMovement==True:
            if moveRight==True:
                player_X+=1
                x_difference-=32
                for i in range(a):
                    coalRect_list[i].x-=32

            elif moveLeft==True:
                player_X-=1
                x_difference+=32
                for i in range(a):
                    coalRect_list[i].x+=32

            elif moveDown==True:
                 player_Y+=1
                 y_difference-=32
                 for i in range(a):
                    coalRect_list[i].y-=32

            elif moveUp==True:
                player_Y-=1
                y_difference+=32
                for i in range(a):
                    coalRect_list[i].y+=32

            else:
                player_X+=0;player_Y+=0
                y_difference+=0;x_difference+=0

            if Space==True:
                sSpace=True
            else:
                sSpace=False
        else:
            pass

        #Drawing objects to screen part
        gameDisplay.fill(white)  #Backgroundcolor

        mapO.update(x_difference,y_difference)
        playerRect=gameDisplay.blit(Images_raw.man_img,(player_X*0+352,player_Y*0+256),None,0)

        aba=playerRect.collidelist(coalRect_list)



        '''
        if aba!=-1 and sSpace==True:
            counter+=1


            if counter==1:
                minedCoal.append(aba)
                mapO.mineCoalAt(aba)
                inventory[0][0]['item']+=1
            elif counter==2:
                counter=0

            else:
                pass
        '''

        if aba!=1:
            if sSpace==True:
                minedCoal.append(aba)
                mapO.mineCoalAt(aba)

            else:
                pass

        #Update everything and set FPS-timer
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(20)

    #Needed so that the program gets closed properly
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#End of the Main game function
#---Normal coding goes on

#call the gameLoop
gameLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with your code, but let's focus on your question:

```
aba=playerRect.collidelist(coalRect_list)
```

`aba` now contains the index of the first `Rect` in `coalRect_list` which collides with `playerRect`, or `-1`.

```
if aba!=1:
    if sSpace==True:
         minedCoal.append(aba)
         mapO.mineCoalAt(aba)
     else:
         pass
```

I guess you wanted to check for `aba != -1` here, since `-1` indicates that no collision happend:

```
if aba != -1 and sSpace:
    ...
```

What now happens is up to you, but I guess you want to remove the coal from the map, so you could simply remove the `Rect` from `coalRect_list`

```
if aba != -1 and sSpace:
    minedCoal.append(aba)
    mapO.mineCoalAt(aba)
    del coalRect_list[aba]
```

Since you only use `coalRect_list` to check whether the coal can be mined, this should be enough.

Comment: This doesnt work because then all the other coalRect are moved to a wrong positon.My point was that , if this statment "if aba != -1 And sSpace:" is true in the minedCoal.append(aba) function the inventory[0][0]['item']+=1 -declaration gets updated just once and not everytime i press space. So just one coal get to added to the inventory.....

Comment: *all the other coalRect are moved to a wrong positon* How? I don't see anything in your code that would cause this.

Comment: Maybe you should make your question more clear. I thought you should only be able to mine the same coal field only once? Not? Then where's your problem exactly?

Comment: yes just once but also adding the coal just once to the inventory not evertime i press the space key. there is the problem i just want that if space is pressed a function or code is called just once and not everytime spacse is predded down

Comment: One last try to understand your question: you should be able to mine each coal field exactly once, but `inventory[0][0]['item']` should never be `>1`? Then why not simply change `inventory[0][0]['item']+=1` to `inventory[0][0]['item']=1`? Or should you only be able to mine extacly *one* coal field?

Comment: your first question : yes but inventory[0][0]['item'] should increase everytime you mine a coal                                                                                   your second question: because invenotry should increase evertime you mine a coal field                                                                                                                     your third question: no you should be able to mine ALL coal fields             TO PUt it simple: 1.player mines coal field-> 2 1coal gets added to inventory , thats what i want to do

Comment: Shouldn't `And` be in lower case..?

Comment: sloth thank for your help , but the main problem is that i have written this dirty code i gona rewrite it nicer and i it will work :D